# Expo CLI not recognised

Tags: reactjs, react-native, error-handling, expo, powershell-cmdlet

im trying to create a new react-native app and to create it i need the expo CLI so i installed it via npm but then after trying to run expo init.... an error response occrured as the following:

expo : The term 'expo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- expo init _______
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (expo:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Would apperciate any help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you could share additional screenshots that would be helpful.

One thing that is super easy to overlook is the path.

For example, you create a new folder "myApp"

Inside that folder you run npm install/expo init/etc.

What this does is creates another folder inside that one.

So your new path should be C://path/myApp/myApp

If you edit your question with screen shots/more info, then I can give a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before and here are some things to try:

- install expo-cli globally (you dont explicitly state you've done this) `npm i -g expo-cli`
- If you  are using PowerShell and  you are getting messages along the line of `expo.ps1 cannot load because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system.` you need to enable script execution. Decide on the script execution scope you want. Choices are Restricted (the current setting if you are getting this message), `AllSigned`, `Unrestricted`, and `RemoteSigned` (probably the one you want). Then open PowerShell as an admin and run

  ```
  Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSign
  ```
- Make sure npm is added to path (on Windows look for `%USERPROFILE%\appData\Roaming\npm`)
- The classic uninstall, reboot, and reinstall